# Proof that Path with admissible edges is shortest

Tags: algorithms, graphs, proof-techniques

Consider an unweighted and directed graph G(V, E). Suppose, for every vertex v ∈ V we assign a vertex label y(v).

We say that the vertex labeling is valid if for every edge (u, v) ∈ E that is directed from u to v, **y(v) − y(u) ≤ 1**.

We say that the edge is admissible if **y(v) − y(u) = 1**. Now consider a directed path P that starts at a vertex x and ends at a vertex y such that P consists **only of admissible edges**.

Show that among all paths between x and y, P has the **fewest** number of edges.

I've tried similar problems where the graph was weighted and the shortest path meant finding the path with least cost. In that case it was pretty easy and could be proven using slack as can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16HETetsB1IRxmEPAyk74HhZKaurAB7Aq/view?usp=sharing)

But I can't figure out the relation between "vertex labels" and "number of edges" in paths. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Makes sense let me add more context.

Comment: @Nathaniel i've improved the question let me know if there's anything else I should add.